# Cent OS NTP Client not Syncing

Tags: centos, ntp

I have an NTP server (Cent OS IP 192.168.102.129) which is configured to sync time from Singapore NTP, the client is from Europe (also a Cent OS 192.168.102.140), I want the client to sync its time from the NTP server, but it doesnt not sync.

I have changed the NTP server's timezone to Singapore, thus not sure if it is the right way, googled and got the NTP server to sync from Singapore NTP server pool, this part works, I can't get the client to sync from the Cent OS NTP Server.

Could some one guide me how to get the client to sync it's time from Singapore while being in Europe.

I tried the settings I used for the NTP server, on the client, with server address of the NTP server, I get this error: no server suitable for synchronization found all the time when I try the ntpq -p command.

Both Cent OS are VM machines

Thank You

Comment: Which `CentOS` version ? If CentOS-7, use `chrony` instead of `ntp`. `ntp` doesn't adjust time if it drifts away faster than a certain value...

Comment: This is CentOS 7, I just wanted to know if my method is correct, for the client to sync time from the NTp server..

Comment: What's the output from `ntpq -pcrv` - Please [edit] your question to include it.